# How can I move config file between esky updates?

Tags: python, esky

I have an ini file that contains the configuration of my app.

Esky creates new folders for the updated versions. How can I make sure that configuration file gets copied?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Perhaps not possible.

However, one can use the `Appdata` folder on Windows systems, and `/etc` folder on Linux systems.